# Proving $\sqrt{2}$ is a real number when the set is bounded from below.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

My professor proved there exists a real number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha^2=2$. He proved the case where the set is bounded from above, namely $S=\{s\in\mathbb{R}:s^2<2\}$. He said a good exercise (not for hw/extra credit/assignment, i.e., for fun)
would be to try to prove it when it is bounded from below, so here is my  attempt but I get stuck very fast.

Proof:

Consider $S=\{s\in\mathbb{R}:s^2>2\}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^2\geq 0$, thus $S\not=\emptyset$ and is a nonnegative set, so it has a lower bound. By the Axiom of Completeness, there exists an $\alpha=\inf S$, we claim $\alpha^2=2$. We will proceed by contradiction by exhausting the cases $\alpha^2>2$ and $\alpha^2 <2$.

(If my logic is correct showing $\alpha^2>2$ contradicts $\alpha$ being a lower bound, and $\alpha^2<2$ contradicts $\alpha$ being the infimum.)

But this is where I get lost, I am not sure if for $\alpha^2>2$ do I look for an element in $S$ smaller than $\alpha$ namely ($\alpha -\frac{1}{n}$) that is larger than 2? As that would show $\alpha$ is not a lower bound, a contradiction to our original assumption.

What I mean if my above assumption is correct am I looking for

$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=& \cdots\text{stuff}\\
>&\cdots\text{less stuff}
\end{align*}
$$
And then show that $(\dots\text{less stuff})>2$?

Your help, advice, and expertise would be appreciated.

Comment: "and bounded from below." well, you have to show that instead of claiming so.

Comment: Does Axiom of completeness not justify it being bounded from below? @mrsamy

Comment: You need to ensure that $s>0$ ie set $S$ consists of positive numbers only. Otherwise $S$ is not bounded from below.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I will make the edits right now, thank you. But my main issue if what I am setting up is correct.

Comment: Rest of your setting is fine. You need to find an $n$ such that $(\alpha-(1/n))^2>2$. Don't solve the inequality to find $n$, just do some gross estimation for $n$ which satisfies this inequality.

Comment: I will work on it and post my solution, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof:

Consider $S=\{s\in\mathbb{R}:s^2>2\}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^2\geq 0$, thus $S\not=\emptyset$ and is a nonnegative set, so it has a lower bound. By the Axiom of Completeness, there exists an $\alpha=\inf S$, we claim $\alpha^2=2$. We will proceed by contradiction by exhausting the cases $\alpha^2>2$ and $\alpha^2 <2$.

for the first case we assume $\alpha^2>2$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=&\alpha^2 -\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\\
>& \alpha^2-\frac{2\alpha}{n}
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\alpha^2>2$,  let $\alpha^2-2=\epsilon >0$, then we have $\displaystyle\alpha^2-\frac{2\alpha}{n}-2=\epsilon -\frac{2\alpha}{n}$

$\displaystyle\epsilon -\frac{2\alpha}{n}>0\Leftrightarrow\epsilon>\frac{2\alpha}{n}\Leftrightarrow\frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}>\frac{1}{n}$

By the Archimedean property, such $n\in\mathbb{N}$ exists, thus $\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{n}\right)\in S$, but  $\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{n}\right) < \alpha$, contradicting our assumption that $\alpha$ is a lower bound.

For the second case we assume $\alpha^2<2$ then

$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=&\alpha^2 +\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\\
<& \alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\\
=&\alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha+1}{n}
\end{align*}
$$
Since we assumed $\alpha^2<2$ we can fix the $\displaystyle\frac{2\alpha+1}{n}$ term such that we are less than 2, that is by the Archimedean property we can find an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$
\frac{1}{n_0}<\frac{2-\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1},\text{ which implies } \frac{2\alpha+1}{n_0}<2-\alpha^2
$$

Then $$ \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 < \alpha^2+(2-\alpha^2)=2$$

Thus $\displaystyle\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is a lower bound for $S$, but $\displaystyle \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)>\alpha$, a contradiction to our assumption that $\alpha =\inf A$.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but an attempt was made!

Comment: Looks fine to me +1. The key is always to get rid of $1/n^2$ suitably.